# Can we make a "Class Level Relationship" in Laravel, as opposed to an "Object Level Relationship"?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Consider the following scenario:

There are couple of entities in my Laravel application like the following:

- `Post`
- `Page`
- `Image`
- `Video`

All the above entities can have `CustomFieldValue`s, which is another entity. The structure of the `custom_field_values` table is as follows:

- ID
- entity_id
- custom_field_definition_id
- value
- [Timestamp fields]

All the `CustomFieldValue`s belong to a single `CustomFieldDefinition` entity. Its table `custom_field_definitions` looks like following:

- ID
- parent_entity_name
- definition_name
- [Timestamp fields]

Following are some sample data from the `custom_field_definitions` table:

```
| ID | parent_entity_name | definition_name   |
|----|--------------------|-------------------|
| 1  | Post               | AuthorTwitterUrl  |
| 2  | Page               | SeoTitle          |
| 3  | Image              | OriginalSourceUrl |
| 4  | Video              | MpaaRating        |
```

As you can see, `CustomFieldDefinition`s are definitions of extra data, that we can store about each type of entity.

Following are some sampel data from the `custom_field_values` table:

```
| ID | entity_id | custom_field_definition_id | value                             |
|----|-----------|----------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| 1  | 1         | 1                          | https://twitter.com/StackOverflow |
| 2  | 1         | 2                          | My Page's SEO Title               |
| 3  | 1         | 3                          | http://example.com/image.jpg      |
| 4  | 1         | 4                          | G – General Audiences             |
```

A little description about the data contained in the `custom_field_values` table:

- `CustomFieldValue:1`: The value for `CustomFieldDefinition:1` and its entity 1 (`Post:1`, in this case, because `CustomFieldDefinition:1` is related to `Post`.) is "https://twitter.com/StackOverflow".
- `CustomFieldValue:2`: The value for `CustomFieldDefinition:2` and its entity 1 (`Page:1`, in this case, because `CustomFieldDefinition:2` is related to `Page`.) is "My Page's SEO Title".
- `CustomFieldValue:3`: The value for `CustomFieldDefinition:3` and its entity 1 (`Image:1`, in this case, because `CustomFieldDefinition:3` is related to `Image`.) is "http://example.com/image.jpg".
- `CustomFieldValue:4`: The value for `CustomFieldDefinition:4` and its entity 1 (`Video:1`, in this case, because `CustomFieldDefinition:4` is related to `Video`.) is "G – General Audiences".

`custom_field_values` table's `entity_id` can refer to any entity class, therefore it is not a foreign key in the DB level. Only in combination with `custom_field_definition_id` we can find to which entity it actually refers to.

---

Now, all is well and good, until I need to add a relationship called `customFieldDefinitions` to any of the entities (Say `Post`.).

```php
class Post extends Model {
 public function customFieldDefinitions(){
  $this -> hasMany ('CustomFieldDefinition');
 }
}
```

The above does not work, because the datapoint that indicates the `CustomFieldDefinition`'s relationship is not a foreign key field in the `custom_field_definitions` table, named `post_id`. We have to somehow build the relationship based on the fact that some records in the `custom_field_definitions` table has "Post" as the value of the field `parent_entity_name`.

```php
CustomFieldDefinition::where('parent_entity_name', '=', 'Post');
```

The above snippet fetches the `CustomFieldDefinition`s that are related to the `Post`, however, it is not possible to do something like the following with the relationship:

```php
class Post extends Model {
 public function customFieldDefinitions(){
  $this
   -> hasMany ('CustomFieldDefinition')
   -> where ('parent_entity_name', '=', 'Post')
  ;
 }
}
```

The `where` constraint works. But Laravel also injects the ID of the current `Post` object into the set of constraints.

So, what I want to do is, not consider the current object's ID at all, and build a "Class Leavel Relationship", and not an "Object Level Relationship".

Is this possible under Laravel?

Comment: '*But Laravel also injects the ID of the current Post object into the set of constraints.*' - This is expected. Your best bet would be to define your own static function which takes the parameter the current post ID.

Comment: @Script47: I am trying to find whether there is a way to accomplish this using proper Laravel relationships, rather than defining my own method that would `return CustomFieldDefinition::where('parent_entity_name', '=', 'Post')->get();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a workaround but I'm not pretty sure about it.

What you could try doing is to define a mutated attribute and set it as the local key of the relationship:

```
class Post extends Model
{

   public function getEntityNameAttribute()
   {
       return 'Post';
   }

   public function customFieldDefinitions()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(
           'CustomFieldDefinition',
           'parent_entity_name',
           'entity_name'
      );
   }
}
```

You could also go further and define a trait which could be used by all your models which have `customFieldDefinitions`. It could look like:

```
trait HasCustomFieldDefinitionsTrait
{
   public function getEntityNameAttribute()
   {
       return (new ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();
   }

   public function customFieldDefinitions()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(
           'CustomFieldDefinition',
           'parent_entity_name',
           'entity_name'
      );
   }
}
```

Then you can use it wherever needed:

```
class Post extends Model
{ 
    use HasCustomFieldDefinitionsTrait;
}

class Video extends Model
{ 
    use HasCustomFieldDefinitionsTrait;
}

class Page extends Model
{ 
    use HasCustomFieldDefinitionsTrait;
}

class Image extends Model
{ 
    use HasCustomFieldDefinitionsTrait;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick!

Thank you so much @Matei Mihai, this saved me a large number of hours.

I posted the same question to `laravel/laravel`, and was asked to post that to `laravel/ideas`, as this was seen as a new idea. I will let it know there that this is indeed doable in the current state of the code.

If you wish, you can cross post the solution here: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1720

Comment: @budhajeewa glad I could help.. I was also curious if it works like this so thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `hasMany()`, you can create `One To Many (Polymorphic)` relationship between `Post`, `Page`, `Image`, `Video` and `CustomFieldDefinition`.

More about polymorphic relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Comment: A polymorphic relationship also expects an `ID` field in the table that is being linked. In your linked article, there's a field named `commentable_id` as well as `commentable_type`.

However, in my `custom_field_definitions` table, there's only `parent_entity_name` there to establish the relationship.

Comment: I see - It's not possible to change change schema of `custom_field_definitions` table? I thought you can do that, that's why I suggested.

Comment: There's nothing to change about `custom_field_definitions` table's schema. There's no ID to be put in there, as that table's records are related to each type of entity, and not individual objects.

In other words, `AuthorTwitterUrl` has a relationship to all `Post`s, not just one `Post`, so it does not make sense to put an ID in there.